# Как обратиться к функции с Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пожалуйста помогите мне с моим небольшим скриптом.

Есть такая функция, но она работает не корректно

Либо я не правильно написал функцию, либо не правильно обращаюсь

```js
function getRes() {

  var url = "https://site.ru/?id=45454";
  $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      var name = field.name;
      return name;
    });
  });

}

//я обращаюсь к ней так, но ниего не выдает

var name = getRes();
```

Comment: Естественно не выдает, так как первая A в ajax значит "Асинхронный".

Comment: а как быть мне? помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Делать что требуется в коллбеке.

Comment: А есть  альтернатива чтоб сделать get запрос и получить json вида
[{name: "vasya"}] ?
В php есть например  для CURL есть аналог file_get_contents

Comment: Я повторяю: все что вам нужно сделать с вашим джсоном или еще с чем - делайте в коллбеке.

Comment: пробовал уже, но у меня в коллбек попадаеют функции для кнопок,  они и перестают работать как оказываются внутри ajax

Comment: Я не телепат и не могу сказать что у вас за функции и почему они не работают. Исправьте вопрос и опишите проблему.

Comment: вытащить из под ajax не получится так как используются переменные ajax ответа

Comment: ладно, спасибо.